# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac 5 4}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac 5 4}}$$
 convergent? If so. what is the radius of convergence?

**My work**

I tried root test  but it gives test inconclusive. which is apt test to use these type of series?

Comment: any body give me the radius of convergence...

Comment: @gloom: It is just a numerical series, not a power series, so you are looking for the radius of convergence of what?

Comment: $\sum a_nx^n$ converges when $|x|<r$ where $r=1/(\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n})$. (Hadamard Radius Formula). In your Q there is no variable. What power series are you asking about,if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac{5}{4}}}=\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}}<\dfrac{e}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}}$

Comment: @gloom: You are welcome.

Comment: what abt the radius of convergence@user170039

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet to be honest. I will include it in the answer if I can find it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac{5}{4}}}
= \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{\frac{5}{4}} \cdot  n^n}
= \frac{1}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}} \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n
=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

And use comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac{5}{4}}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}n^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{4}} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^{5/4}}
$$
You know $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+1/n)^n=e$. Then use the comparison test.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac{5}{4}}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^{5/4}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e}{n^{5/4}}
$$
And the series on the right converges either by the integral test or by the $p$-test.